# Probability for the Sums of Random Variables

Tags: probability

From a Probability perspective, I am curious to learn about the distribution of the sums of Random Variables.

For example, suppose I am playing a game in which I flip a fair coin. The probability of getting a heads is 0.5 and the probability of getting a tails is also 0.5.

Let's say that if I get a heads, my score = score + 1. And if I get a tails, my score = score -1

Suppose my current score is 7 - **after 3 flips, what is the probability that my score will be greater than or equal to 7?**

To answer this question, I can manually ennumerate all possible combinations given my current score and 3 flips:

- Combination 1: $7 + 1 -1 + 1 = 8$
- Combination 2: $7 + 1 -1 -1 = 6$
- Combination 3: $7 + 1 +1 +1 = 10$
- Combination 4: $7 + 1 +1 -1 = 8$
- Combination 5: $7 -1 -1 -1 = 4$
- Combination 6: $7 -1 -1 +1 = 6$
- Combination 7: $7 + 1 -1 +1 = 8$
- Combination 8: $7 -1 +1 +1 = 8$

Then, I can count how many of these combinations result in a score greater than 7.

Here, I can see that out of the 8 possible combinations ($2^3 = 8$), 3 of these combinations have a score less than 7 - therefore, the probability that my score will be greater than or equal to 7 after 3 flips is  $5/8$

**My Question:** Now, I am interested in solving these kinds of problems from a more math based perspective. For example, suppose you current score is $m$ and you flip the coin $n$ times, what is the probability that my final score will be greater than $k$?

Currently, I would solve this kind of question via simulation - I would repeatedly simulate games based on the initial conditions and record the final score. Below is some Python code to represent this problem (when current score = 7 and there are 100 flips):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def flip_coin():
    return np.random.choice([-1, 1])

def simulate_game(num_flips):
    score = 7
    scores = [score]
    for i in range(num_flips):
        score += flip_coin()
        scores.append(score)
    return scores

num_sims = 1000
num_flips = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['simulation number', 'total end score'])

for i in range(num_sims):
    scores = simulate_game(num_flips)
    df.loc[i] = [i+1, scores[-1]]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5))

# Plot the simulations
for i in range(num_sims):
    scores = simulate_game(num_flips)
    # Map score values to a color using a colormap
    color = cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')((scores[-1] - df['total end score'].min()) / 
                                  (df['total end score'].max() - df['total end score'].min()))
    axs[0].plot(range(num_flips+1), scores, color=color)
axs[0].set_xlabel('Turn number')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Score value')
axs[0].set_title(f'{num_sims} simulations of the coin flip game')

# Plot the density plot
# Use the same colormap to color the plot
df['total end score'].plot(kind='density', ax=axs[1], cmap='RdYlBu')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Total end score')
axs[1].set_title('Density plot of total end scores')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Based on the accumulated information from these simulations, I could count the number of simulations in which the final score was greater than $k$ and divide this number by the total number of simulations. And the more simulations I performed, the closer this calculation will be to the real number.

**But how can we solve this problem mathematically? Is there some general mathematical result on the sums of Random Variables?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your combination 1=7. 7 should read (- + -)=6 and so p(score>7)=4/8

Comment: Enumerating the solutions *is* solving it mathematically. In general, if you have a sum of *independent* random variables there isn't really a clean formula for the distribution of that sum. However for lots of specific distributions, there is...

Comment: @ Piita: thank you for your reply!

Comment: @ Fshrike: thank you for your reply! I did not know of such a formula exists...

Comment: For general distributions, you can use convolution technique or using the MGF / Characteristic function with the inverting technique. Unfortunately most of them we do not have a nice closed form solution. For this question, we have the sum of Bernoulli random variables which has the Binomial distribution, so the problem can be expressed in terms of the Binomial distribution.

Comment: @ BGM: thank you for your reply! Can you please write this Convolution formula if you have time? Thanks!